# Passing table values as function arguments in Lua 4 without the "call" function

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

I have a table of values that can in principle be of any length:

```
Points =
{
    "Point #1",
    "Point #5",
    "Point #7",
    "Point #10",
    "Point #5",
    "Point #11",
    "Point #5",
}
```

I want to pass them as arguments to a function.

```
addPath(<sPathName>, <sPoint>, <sPoint>, ...)
```

Now, normally you could use the "call" function. But in the software I am using this function is unavailable and not in scope.

How do I get around this problem in Lua 4?

[edit]

[Here](http://hw2wiki.net/wiki.hw2.info/ScopeLevel.html) are the functions I *can* use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In newer versions of Lua, you'd use `unpack`, as in `addPath(sPathName,unpack(Points))`, but Lua 4.0 does not have `unpack`.

If you can add C code, `unpack` from Lua 5.0 works fine in 4.0:

```
static int luaB_unpack (lua_State *L) {
  int n, i;
  luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);
  n = lua_getn(L, 1);
  luaL_checkstack(L, n, "table too big to unpack");
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++)  /* push arg[1...n] */
    lua_rawgeti(L, 1, i);
  return n;
}
```

Add this to `lbaselib.c` and this to `base_funcs`:

```
  {"unpack", luaB_unpack},
```

If you cannot add C code, then you're out of luck and are probably reduced to this hack:

```
function unpack(t)
  return t[1],t[2],t[3],t[4],t[5],t[6],t[7],t[8],t[9],t[10]
end
```

Extend the return expression as needed but you may only go as far as 200 or so. Let's hope that `addPath` ignores or stops at the first `nil`.

You can also try this one, which stops at the first nil but has no explicit limits (there are recursion limits and it'll only handle up to 250 table entries):

```
function unpack(t,i)
        i = i or 1
        if t[i]~=nil then
                return t[i],unpack(t,i+1)
        end
end
```

Comment: How do I then pass them to the function?